# There is already an object named 'xxx' in the database for already existing database

Tags: entity-framework

I'm getting the error

```
There is already an object named '__MigrationHistory' in the database
```

when running the following command:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

I searched something on stackoverflow and found that there is need to run the following commands:

```
Add-Migration Initial -IgnoreChanges
Update-Database -verbose
```

Since the database already existed, I'm adding extra tables to it.

My question is, the above suggested commands just modifies the table definition or there is some alteration in data for example clears it or something like that.

Cause it has live data in it so I don't want to loose it. Would help a lot with the reply.

Comment: Have you deleted your migration folder from your project and trying to add a new migration, isn't it?

Comment: i don't know what would be the repercussions.

Comment: Actually your migration folder in you project and database has been out of sync. You can overcome this problem in various ways according to what you actually with the current state of the database.

Comment: see in my database there is already migration history table , so whenever I'm creating a table via class, add migration and update through ef, it gives the already exist error. So how can I achieve this. with the above two commands , is it possible and if will that affect my data?